# How to make an animated model jump in BGE

Tags: game-engine, physics

My rigged and animated human model actually jumps when i press the required key, but doesn't fall again n the ground. I have tried to click the jump motion actuator and/or increase z motion, but the model just floats in the air higher every jump. Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `Character` type physics to your object.

Go to the `Properties` panel, and under the `Physics` tab, change the type from `Static` to `Character` and Check collision bounds; Depending on what your character looks like, you may want to change the `Bounds` type. As your character is rigged, you'll have to check `Compound`. You also can tweak the settings if you would like to modify the margin between objects, when colliding.

Comment: In the model or in the armature?

Comment: Let's see... The Armature is parented to the Character, right? If so, then the object; And check `Compound`.

Comment: I am working on blender 2.66a

Comment: @GonzaloGómezFernández Is there no such option, then? Why don't you update?

Comment: I have blender 2.7 but if i open my old file i lost animation

Comment: @GonzaloGómezFernández Okay, but does it not work in 2.66a?

Comment: Rigid or soft body? I can't find character anyway on none of them...

Comment: @GonzaloGómezFernández Character